# NextJS 13.4 problems with aws amplify authenticator

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I want to go from CRA to nextjs but I am having troubles integrating AWS Amplify authentication.
The amplify login form does show up but when trying to sign in it gives me the following error:

**Error**

```
[ERROR] 40:38.8 AuthError - 
            Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. 
            The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
            This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:

            1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
                See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information

            2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js) for help upgrading Amplify packages.
```

**src/app/layout.tsx**

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from "../aws-exports";

Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**src/app/page.tsx**

```
"use client"
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default withAuthenticator(Home);
```

- Tried a fresh install of NextJS
- `amplify pull`

Answer (score 1):

Please try configuring Amplify with your exports file in `page.tsx` instead of `layout.tsx`.

**src/app/page.tsx**

```
'use client';

import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import awsExports from '../aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsExports);

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default withAuthenticator(Home);
```

**src/app/layout.tsx**

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is what I seem to be doing. I am confused by the "use client" and how that relates to security. Does this expose the `aws-exports` to the client? Just trying out this `app` directory approach in place of the `pages` dir when it comes to nextJS 13.

Answer (score 1):

I found https://github.com/NeiruBugz/next-cognito-auth/blob/main/app/auth/provider.tsx this as the working way to provide Amplify Auth mechanism for Next.js App Router project. So, you just have a client component as a Provider, where you configure Amplify once and wrap any child with this Provider. Also, you can just return `null`, configure Amplify and put this component in RootLayout like `<AmplifyProvider />`

A little notice: I'm using Amplify just as an Auth provider with my own UI

Answer (score 0):

Glad to answer this question. In the App Router, it introduces Server Components and Client Components. There is a clear network boundary between Server Components and Client Components. JS code in Server Components only gets executed and kept on the server.

Amplify Authenticator works as a Client Component. In order to get it working properly. You need to ensure configure it properly with `Amplify.configure` on the client side. By adding `'use client'` directive to the top of a file, you let the router know the code within the file is supposed to be executed on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Amplify is a client-side library. For all client-side libraries in Nextjs 13, you need to create a provider and wrap it in layout file.

In this case,

**src/lib/providers.tsx**

```
"use client";

import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "../aws-exports";
import "@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css";

Amplify.configure({ ...awsconfig, ssr: true });

export default function AmplifyProvider({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

**layout.tsx**

```
import AmplifyProvider from "@/lib/providers";
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <AmplifyProvider>
        <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      </AmplifyProvider>
    </html>
  );
}
```